# partially bold ggplot2 guide labels based on condition

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I have some tidy data that I want to plot, combining two columns for
grouping.

In the legend, I want to print one of the entries in one of those columns in
bold face.

Here is a minimal working example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot.data <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10,
                        class1=rep(letters[1:2], 10),
                        class2=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=5))

# This class should be displayed in bold
# Might be subject to change; consider it a function parameter
class2.bold <- "A"

# This is the default
# Note that the used classes are automagically determined from the data
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=paste(class1, class2, sep="/"))) +
  scale_color_discrete("class")

# This is what I want
# Note that it only works because I know the data used in this example
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=paste(class1, class2, sep=" / "))) +
  scale_color_discrete("class",
                       label=c(expression(a / bold(A)),
                               expression(a / B),
                               expression(b / bold(A)),
                               expression(b / B)))
```

How can I get the second plot by utilizing `class2.bold` and `plot.data`
only (i.e. without further knowledge of their content as of writing the code)?

For example, when I change `class2.bold` to `"B"` and add more data rows to
`plot.data` that feature addional `class1` and `class2` values/combinations, I
still want the plot command to work without the need for manual adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. There might be a faster way but this gets there.

Your code:

```
  plot.data <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10,
                            class1=rep(letters[1:2], 10),
                            class2=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=5))
    
    # This class should be displayed in bold
    # Might be subject to change; consider it a function parameter
    class2.bold <- "A"
    
    # This is the default
    # Note that the used classes are automagically determined from the data
    ggplot(plot.data, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_point(aes(color=paste(class1, class2, sep="/"))) +
      scale_color_discrete("class")
```

For bolded labels:

```
 #get unique labels
    legend_labs <- unique(paste(plot.data$class1, plot.data$class2, sep="/"))
    
    #order them in alphabetical order
    legend_labs <- legend_labs[order(legend_labs)]
    
    #Bold the correct letters
    legend_labs <- sub(pattern = class2.bold,
        replacement = paste0("bold(",class2.bold,")"),
        legend_labs)
    
    #make them expressions
    legend_labs <- lapply(parse(text = legend_labs), as.expression)
    
    #plot
    ggplot(plot.data, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_point(aes(color=paste(class1, class2, sep=" / "))) +
      scale_color_discrete("class",
                           label=legend_labs)
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to bold more than more letter use this the third step instead

```
#Bold the correct letters
for (i in 1:length(class2.bold)) {
legend_labs <- sub(pattern = class2.bold[i],
    replacement = paste0("bold(",class2.bold[i],")"),
    legend_labs)
}
```